# Node/NPM not resolving modules from local node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am on Windows and my app is located at folder `H../my-app`. `my-app` has a `node_modules` folder which has all the required modules installed. However, when I compile the app by typing the script command in terminal, Node starts looking for modules in `C:/Developer...` and gives error that `xyz` module not found, even though it is present in `my-app/node_modules`. Why is this happening?

I understand that Node will look for modules in global directory if not found locally, but that's also not the case here as my global node directory is in `H` drive, not `C`.

I cannot log the entire error here as I am working on a remote machine and there is no way I can copy code out of it, but here is a line of error as logged into `npm-debug.log`:

`verbose stack Exit Status 1`

`verbose stack at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:..\node\6.3.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16`

Comment: What's the output of "npm config get prefix"? Type this command on terminal.

Comment: What is the compilation script command that you're using?

Comment: @jahuuar: that gives the path of global node_modules folder, which is in `H:` drive.

Comment: @laggingreflex: I am typing `npm run storybook`. You can get more information about storybook here https://storybook.js.org/basics/introduction/